# Ansible 2: Is it possible to use a variable as a dictionary key

Tags: ansible

I want to use a variable to define which interface I want to use.

And the following playbook doesn't work:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    eth_to_use: eth0
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{ansible_{{eth_to_use}}.ipv4.address}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about this way:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    eth_to_use: en0
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_'+eth_to_use].ipv4[0].address}}"
```

Comment: @NelsonG `ipv4` is a list here, so you can't just call `ipv4.address`